# "Bearing" question - finding distance between two objects

Tags: trigonometry

I am having problem solving the following question related to "bearing" in trigonometry.

**A motorboat is 10 km South of a lighthouse and is on a course of 053 degrees. What is the shortest distance between the motorboat and the lighthouse?**

My confusion is how does a boat travel 10 km South of a lighthouse and making an angle of 53 degrees clockwise from North. Is there something wrong with the question itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a drawing of the problem I made (Excuse my bad drawing skills).

[image]

**LH** represents the lighthouse, and **MB** represents the motorboat.

Here, the motorboat is travelling at a $53^{\circ}$ angle from North.

Now, here is the important part to notice: The shortest distance will be the point when the **perpendicular of the black line** (The path which the motorboat goes) intersects the light house.

Therefore, the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ line is the shortest distance. This length can easily be calculated using trigonometry:

$10\sin{53^{\circ}}\approx \boxed{7.986 \text{ km}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Really helped me understanding and solving the question. Highly appreciate it.